# Using stored procedure within transactionscope

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, transactions, transactionscope

I execute a stored procedure in my c# application, should I enclose it using TransactionScope as below ?

```
protected void rbl_SystemStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        AdminData.myFunction();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

myFunction() executes a stored procedure in my SQL Server Database, and the stored procedure content is like below

```
UPDATE Table A SET...
UPDATE Table B SET ...
DELETE FROM Table C WHERE ...
```

Comment: "should I enclose it ..." is a question that only *you* can answer - do you want/need all 3 statements within the procedure to run inside a single transaction?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my question is related to syntax, I wonder if I write my code like above, all 3 statements should run together otherwise they won't be running, and If I don't write my code like above one can run and others may not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"should I" is subjective and contextual (it might not be enabled, for example; or you might  use connection-based transactions; or you might not need *any* transaction); but it is certainly an option that is available to you. Whether it is "as below" depends on exactly where the connection is created/opened, as connections will only automatically enlist in a transaction-scope it they are initialized *inside* the transaction-scope. If the connection is created/opened inside `myFunction`, then yes it should work (caveat: unless the connection-string has `Enlist` explicitly set to false).

Comment: my question was related to syntax, and I understand from what you wrote, if transactionscope is enclosing (con.open - con.close) sections, any process completed using this con will be canceled if a single error is encauntered, is that correct ?

Comment: @HOY again, that depends on code that I can't see. **IF** the connection is created *inside* the transaction-scope, and **IF** the connection-string doesn't deliberately prevent enlist, then yes. Also, I can't remember the exact scenarios, but in some early implementations (and I'm noting the "sql-server-2005" tag here) there were some scenarios that could lead to SPIDs *losing* their ambient transaction, and working in the nul-transaction instead. Fixed for ages, but: that is an old version.